# How do I perform a correlation analysis between the years and CO2 emissions per state, in my data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a statistical correlation analysis between years and C02 emissions per state in my data, but I can't seem to get the coding correct.

I've added the graph I created using the data I'm trying to perform the statistical analysis on below.

Graph of years and C02 emissions per state:

[image: Graph of years and C02 emissions per state]

I tried using the following coding

```
correlations <- co2emissionsdata %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise( correlations = cor( Year, `CO2 Emissions Per Capita (tonne)`))
print(correlations)
```

And the answer I got is below this text, which I don't think is what I was looking for, for my data analysis.

```
State correlations
<chr>        <dbl>
1 ACT         -0.688
2 NSW         -0.984
3 NT          -0.523
4 QLD         -0.931
5 SA          -0.770
6 TAS         -0.924
7 VIC         -0.947
8 WA          -0.198
```

Comment: the output is a correlation of Year and CO2 emissions. it's just different correlation results for each state. what can you clarity what exactly are you looking for? do you want  only a single value to represent the relationship of Year and CO2 emissions?  instead of different values for each state ?

Comment: Oh I see now, that's actually what I wanted haha I am very new at this, I was expecting other things to come from the test. Trying to find out what other tests I can perform to analyse this data.

Comment: Well it looks like Time Series Analysis would per appropriate for this type of the data.  And I think you should transfer this question to Cross Validate since it is more of a statistics/analysis question.

Comment: Testing for and quantifying trends (assuming that is what you want) in time series isn't trivial. For example: `cor(1:20, cumsum(rnorm(20)))`